# How to prepare array by making two API calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, parse-platform

I'm making an "API" call for getting a list of "MyMusic" album. It returns array of music ids and those ids are linked with another table. So in order to get music details like name etc. I need to make separate "API" calls with id.

What is the recommended way to make "API" calls to fill my array with music details.

Comment: Please show the signatures of the two APIs that you need to call.

Comment: API and JSONs are pretty simple and straightforward. Response is json of music ids. And if I make another API call with id then it will return object of music detail.

Comment: Why are you using afnetworking to access parse.com data?

Comment: @Handsomeguy sorry removed. Got tagged unknowingly.

Comment: Ok, what kind of API call are you getting JSON from?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on if the API can return multiple id's. Can you send a JSON-array to the API and get an array in return? If not, it looks like you have to send the id's one at a time.

Comment: JSON is pretty simple and straightforward. it is array of music ids. And if I make another API call with id then it will retun object of music detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't for some reason NEED to use the REST api (which it seems you are doing now), then in your first query use `includeKey` on the field that contains the IDs. If this field is a Pointer to another table, this will make sure the full objects are returned in the first query instead of just the pointers.